# How can I upgrade a package recursively in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, freebsd

Is there any equivalent to FreeBSD's `portupgrade -R` in Arch Linux?
From `man portupgrade`:

> ```
>  -R
>  --upward-recursive     Act on all those packages required by the given
>                         packages as well.
> ```

Comment: I'm confused, is what your asking for the same things as [this, stating that partial upgrades are unsupported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported)?

Comment: @sr_ I want to upgrade a package and everything it depends on. I would like to avoid the full upgrade with `pacman -Syu`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arch Linux package manager, `pacman` automatically manages dependencies.

If by `ports` you mean those third-party packages provided by Arch users in the unsupported repo (AUR), then some of the AUR helpers have an option to update dependencies. Yaourt, for example, will do this.

However, as the [yaourt page on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt) makes clear, it is neither wise nor advisable to completely automate this recursively.

Given the number of packages in Arch's official repos, this is not really an issue. There will be very few packages from AUR that have extensive dependencies, so upgrading them individually is neither difficult nor onerous.

Comment: Does `pacman -S some_package` automaticaly syncs the packages wich some_package depends on?

Comment: Yes. It will pull in the required dependencies.